# Help suggest an algorithm for online update of eigenvalues/eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

We need guide here. The situation is that we have a dynamically changing large matrix, say 10,000 rows and columns. Each time, there is about 10% change: some rows are added, removed, or updated.

We want to use principal component analysis to monitor the largest eigenvalue and eigenvector of the covariance matrix. Since each time the majority of the matrix stay the same, we want to update the previously computed eigenvalue and eigenvector based the change, rather than recompute the whole thing.

We searched and found several papers about [online PCA](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/papers/opca.pdf), but they only concern adding rows one by one. We are asking if anyone can help suggest an appropriate PCA algorithm for our above purpose.